# CakePHP 3 : Retrieving data from database using Ajax

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-ajaxhelper

I am working on a CakePHP 3 project which is having a `Apply Coupon` form.

I want to apply the coupon using Ajax.

The view of coupon form is

```
<?= $this->Form->create(null, [
  'url' => ['controller' => 'Coupons', 'action' => 'checkCoupon'],
  'name' => 'checkCoupon'
]) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('coupon_code', [
  'type' => 'text',
  'placeholder' => 'Apply Coupon Code',
  'label' => false
]) ?>
<?= $this->Form->submit('Apply Coupon') ?>
```

and the `checkCoupon` action in `CouponsController` is

```
public function checkCoupon()
{
  $this->request->onlyAllow('ajax'); // No direct access via browser URL

  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $couponCode = $this->request->data['coupon_code'];
    $couponCheck = $this->Coupons->find('all', [
      'conditions' => [
      'coupon_code' => $couponCode
      ]
    ]);
    if ($couponCheck->count() === 1) {
       $coupon = $couponCheck->first();
       $valid_till = $coupon->valid_till;
       $dt = new Time($valid_till);
       $date = $dt->format('Y-m-d');

       if ($date >= date('Y-m-d')) {
         echo 'Coupon is Valid. Discount of '.$coupon->value.'has been applied';
       } else {
         echo 'Coupon is Expired';
       }
    } else {
       echo 'This is not a valid coupon code';
    }
  }
}
```

I want the `$coupon->value` and `$coupon->id` to be retrieved and added to the checkout link as

```
<?= $this->Html->link(__('Confirm Checkout'), ['controller' => 'ServiceRequests', 'action' => 'confirmCheckout', $service->id, $primaryAddressId, $serviceArea->id, $coupon->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-block btn-success']) ?>
```

The `Apply Coupon` form is in `checkout` action of `RequestsController`
Also the form is working well. I have checked it by removing the `onlyAllow('ajax')` line and printing values in `check_coupon.ctp` view.

How could I do it using Ajax ?

> Edit 2 : checkout.ctp

```
<div class="form-info coupon">
  <?= $this->Form->create(null, [
    'url' => ['controller' => 'Coupons', 'action' => 'ajax_checkCoupon'],
    'name' => 'checkCoupon',
    'id' => 'checkCoupon'
  ]) ?>
  <?= $this->Form->input('coupon_code', [
    'type' => 'text',
    'placeholder' => 'Apply Coupon Code',
    'label' => false
  ]) ?>
  <label class="hvr-sweep-to-right">
    <?= $this->Form->submit('Apply Coupon', ['id' => 'applyCoupon']) ?>
  </label>
  <label id="couponUpdate"></label>
  <label id="loading" style="display:none;">Loading...</label>
  <?php
     $data = $this->Html->script('#checkCoupon')->serializeForm(['isForm' => true, 'inline' => true]);
     $this->Html->script('#checkCoupon')->event(
       'submit',
       $this->Html->script(
        [
          'controller' => 'Coupons',
          'action' => 'ajax_checkCoupon'
        ],
        [
          'update' => '#couponUpdate',
          'data' => $data,
          'async' => true,
          'dataExpression' => true,
          'before' => "$('#loading').fadeIn();$('#applyCoupon').attr('disabled','disabled');",
          'complete' => "$('#loading').fadeOut();$('#applyCoupon').removeAttr('disabled');"
        ]
      )
    );
   ?>
  </div>
```

***Error : Call to a member function serializeForm() on string on line 18 in `checkout.ctp`***

Comment: Where would a `request->onlyAllow()` method come from in CakePHP3 ?

Comment: I get this from a [tutorial](http://miftyisbored.com/a-complete-tutorial-on-cakephp-and-ajax-forms-using-jquery/)

Comment: Near the bottom of that tutorial, the author covers the Javascript code required to post the form via ajax. Is that Javascript included in your view or layout code?

Comment: Yes I tried, but it is giving error as `Call to a member function serializeForm() on string`. on `checkout.ctp`. I have added the code inside `checkout.ctp`

Comment: Don't use tutorials for non-matching versions! The linked on is for CakePHP 2.x, in 3.x there is no JS helper anymore. **http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=submit+form+ajax**

Comment: I googled every where but there is nowhere tutorial for CakePHP 3. I'm new to CakePHP and as well Ajax. Can you suggest any tutorial or any plugin ?